# Xamarin - Saving List of objects to file

Tags: c#, xamarin

I spent a few days searching for this and I [found a tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) on how to save text but, since I'm beginer at Xamarin, I don't know how to modify that solution for saving a list of objects.

I have an object `Clothes` with two properties (`string img_path` and `string img_tag`). Then I have a List of `Clothes`. I wanna be able to save List to a file and later be able to load the Clothes from that file into the List of Clothes.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us what you tried already?

Comment: use `Json.net` to serialize your list to `json` (this will return string) and the write the file to device storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) and then you can simply serialize you object into a json string:

```cs
//Your list
var list = new List<Clothes>();
//A string with your list of Clothes
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Save it normally, using the tutorial you posted on the question and when you need to load your list again, simply do something like this:

```cs
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Clothes>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the built-in DataContractSerializer and annotate your class with the requisite [DataContract] and [DataMember] annotations. You will then be able to write out your class as an XML file. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details on how to use this functionality.